# burn function in reflect finance

Tags: solidity

I am trying to add a burn function into the reflect finance code - trying to burn x% and redistribute y%. I made a small edit to the transfer function and I feel it should work. Could you please look at this and let me know if I am missing something:

```
function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)
    public
    override
    returns (bool)
{
    uint256 burnAmt = amount.mul(_burnFee) / 100; // calculate the burn Amount
    _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount.sub(burnAmt)); // in current reflect code
    _tTotal -= burnAmt; // reducing the total supply by burn amount. For this I had to make the tTotal number not constant
    Transfer(_msgSender(), address(0), burnAmt); // tranferring burn amount to a zero address

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it needs (a lot) more focus. You are basically asking "Considering the whole codebase of Reflect Finance, can you audit my new function"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.